# Can I get a partial refund from SNCF?

Tags: trains, france, tickets, high-speed-rail, sncf

I purchased a train ticket from Cherbourg to Reims from [TGV Europe](http://www.tgv-europe.com). This was two trains, a TER service from Cherbourg to Paris, and a double-decker TGV from Paris to Reims. The TGV part was a "prem", and if I cancel the ticket I'll lose money. But that's okay, because I don't want to cancel that ticket: I still want the TGV from Paris to Reims, but I no longer want the TER from Cherbourg to Paris.

Is there any way I can cancel only the first part of the ticket? I cannot find this option on the website, and they don't provide contact details anywhere obvious.

Comment: Have you tried calling them as the website suggests? http://www.voyages-sncf.co.uk/Default.aspx?tabid=2891

Comment: @Karlson. Would that work? "Also bear in mind that we can only exchange and refund tickets issued by Rail Europe, the SNCF’s official UK ticket agent." I suppose it's no harm trying. I shall.

Comment: If you bought in the UK that should work.  It also might work in France but I can't read French for the France site.

Answer (score 5):

Whether you can get a refund on a ticket will depend on the fare conditions of that ticket. Your confirmation should make clear of these conditions and you'll have been made aware of them prior to purchase.

If you booked a cheap advance fare by TER Corail (in the region of about £18-20) then this will likely be a non flexible meaning it's not refundable nor exchangeable. Flexible fares on that route are more in the region of £40-45 but are either fully refundable or refundable with a 10% fee retained.

Comment: Do you have any source to back this up? I cannot check for the whole route as Cherbourg-Paris is no more in TER, but Cherbourg-Caen always costs 22.9 euros (as of May 2015) for a full price.

Answer (score 3):

As of May 2015, Cherbourg-Paris cannot be done entirely on a TER, but rather on an Intercités train. The fare conditions of a SNCF ticket (cardboard or e-ticket) are usually listed on the ticket.

For an Intercités ticket bought on [voyages-sncf.com](http://en.voyages-sncf.com) (tgv-europe.com no longer exists) on the Leisure fare for Cherbourg-Paris, it is possible to cancel it for free until the day before the departure, with a fee of 50% (max of 12 euros) on the day of departure. After departure, it is non-refundable.

> Billet échangeable et remboursable sans frais jusqu'à la veille du départ, avec une retenue de 50% plafonnée à 12 € et réajustement au tarif en vigueur le jour du départ, non échangeable et non remboursable après départ.

In general, on SNCF tickets bought online at voyages-sncf.com or in a station or at a ticket machine on the Leisure fare, the conditions are similar: free for exchange and refund until the day before departure, exhangeable and refundable on the day of departure for a fee, and non-exchangeable and non-refundable after departure.

Prem's tickets are non-exchangeable and non-refundable.

To modify your ticket online, find your ticket reference number (6 alphanumeric characters), and go to the [reservation manager](http://en.voyages-sncf.com/en/train-services/order-follow-up).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an actual printed ticket, printed on SNCF card stock? In that case you could get a refund if it's a normally priced ticket. Just go to the ticket window at any station. However, if it's an electronic ticket, then you can't get a refund, as there is no way for SNCF to reverse the sale.

Comment: Do you have any source to back this up? I have cancelled >10 electronic tickets bought from voyages-sncf.com, without any issue.